# iOS Core Data save context error

Tags: ios, core-data

Im trying to insert data to database by using Core Data:

```
+ (BOOL)insertQuestionnaireObject:(Questionnaire *)questionnaireObject withError:(NSError **)error
{
    __block BOOL result = NO;

    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{

        Questionnaire *questionnaireManagedObject = [self entityToInsertWithName:@"Questionnaire"];

        if (questionnaireManagedObject)
        {
            [self prepareForInsertQuestionnaireManagedObject:questionnaireManagedObject withQuestionnaireObject:questionnaireObject];

            result = [self saveContextWithError:error];
        }
    }];

    return result;
}
```

I am saving context:

```
+ (BOOL)saveContextWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    BOOL result = YES;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:error])
    {
        result = NO;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Insert method at first look works normally. I can't tell the same about save context method. It loops (why the hell it should?) in line `if (![self.managedObjectContext save:error])` and exits without going to line `return result;` with our a crash or returned error. But it saves 2x objects to database instead of 1. These things started to happen since iOS 8 and methods `performBlockAndWait`usage. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are trying to access an instance variable by calling `self.managedObjectContext` within the class method. Try making the class method into a instance method or, pass `self.managedObjectContext` as a parameter to the class method.